# Django If statement in HTML not responding

Tags: python, django

I am trying to show in a nav bar an option where if the user is the designer it appears to him to direct him to user-posts.

I know that the link is working because in the post list and post detail when I click the user name it directs me to the user-posts, I am trying to do the same in the nav bar

Here is is the template

```
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
{% if object.designer == user %}
<a class="dropdown-item" href=" {% url 'score:user-posts' post.designer.username %} ">Submitted Posts</a>
{% endif %}
```

Here is the post-detail link that I am trying to imitate

```
<a class="post_name" href="{% url 'score:user-posts' object.designer.username %}">
{{ object.designer }}
</a>
```

Here is the list view as well link to users post:

```
<a href="{% url 'score:user-posts' post.designer.username %}">{{ post.designer }}</a>
```

Here is the User list view

```
class UserPostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = "user_posts.html"
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    paginate_by = 5

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
        return Post.objects.filter(designer=user).order_by('-date_posted')
```

Comment: If the link is not showing up, you should double check your if statement, and possibly be more explicit in your checking: `{% if object.designer.username == user.username %}`

Comment: Another way to troubleshoot is to drop the context into the html template and see what gets printed: `{{ object.designer }} "should equal" {{ user }}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the issue but:

```
{% url 'score:user-posts' post.designer.username %}
```

In the nav-bar this should probably be:

```
{% url 'score:user-posts' user.username %}
```

Other than that check that `user` and `object.designer` are what you expect them to be.

Helping would be easier if you could share the views / tell what's in the context